# LAG function doesn't complete

Tags: sas, lag

I am constructing a life table. My data looks like this:

```
age    npx       
=================
0-1    0.996
1-4    0.9955
5-9    0.9966
```

I want to construct a new variable `lx`. The value of `lx` for `age="0-1"` is `100,000`.
The value for `"1-4"` will be `lx * npx` for the previous record.

here's my code:

```
 if age = "0-1" then lx = 100000;
 lag_lx  = lag1 (lx);
 lag_npx = lag1 (npx);

 lx = lag_lx * lag_npx;
```

What happens is that the program stops calculating `lx` after the 2nd record;
From record 3 on, `lx` has `.` (missing)

Comment: At each iteration of the data step `lx` is initialized to missing, and it's only assigning `lx` if `age = "0-1"`. But that condition is only true in the first record, so `lx` is missing in the others. To fix that, add `retain lx;` at the top of the data step.

Answer (score 4):

I would go down the `ifn` route here as it doesn't screw up what you think is the lagged value and it makes the code very simple (have a read of [this paper](http://www.howles.com/saspapers/CC33.pdf)).  You also need a `retain` statement as stated by @Alex A.

```
data have;
    input age $ npx;
    datalines;
0-1    0.996
1-4    0.9955
5-9    0.9966
;

data want;
set have;
retain lx;
lx = ifn(age='0-1',100000,lx*lag(npx));
run;
```

Comment: Yes, this worked, although it didn't look right until I realized that the lx on the right side is the (retained) old value, while the lx on the left is the newly calculated value. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the values are stored in LAG only when LAG is used. From support.sas.com:   "Storing values at the bottom of the queue and returning values from the top of the queue occurs only when the function is executed. An occurrence of the LAGn function that is executed conditionally will store and return values only from the observations for which the condition is satisfied. "

This code is not pretty and can be improved, but it does the job.

```
data have;
    input age $ npx;
    datalines;
0-1    0.996
1-4    0.9955
5-9    0.9966
;

data want;
    set have;   
    IF _N_ = 1 Then lx = 100000;
            lag_lx  = lag(lx);
            lag_npx = lag(npx);
    IF _N_ ne 1 Then lx = lag_lx * lag_npx;
            lag_lx  = lag(lx);
            lag_npx = lag(npx);
    IF _N_ ne 1 Then lx = lag_lx * lag_npx;
RUN;
```

Comment: The trick is to either use `lag` within an `ifn` statement or put the `lag` statement before the `if` statement. Using a `retain` statement as suggested by @Alex A will fix the other issue (and means you wouldn't need as many `if` statements in your answer).

Comment: Vasili -  here is what I put in: